# navigationController?.pushViewController is not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a **collection view controller**. In **collectionView cell** I have label which I made clickable to **push** to the nextViewController.

I know that problem in navigationController. But I'm new in swift so can't fix. Hope you guys can help me.

Here's my SceneDelegate:

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    // Create the root view controller as needed
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
    
    let win = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    win.rootViewController = nc
    win.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window = win
```

and my label:

```
    let text = UILabel()
    text.text = "something"
    text.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addSubview(text)
    
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PopularCellTwo.labelTapped))
    text.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

    @objc func labelTapped() {
        let nextVC = NextViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        print("labelTapped tapped")
    
    }
```

I also added screenshot. When I click on "Something" It should go next page.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oYwb.png

Comment: your collectionView have NavigationController but your cell does not have that ... use closure or delegate pattern to  navigate

Comment: @jawadAli you mean like this:  weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?

Comment: It didn't help. I mean, project builds, and "label tapped" prrints in console, but push not working

Comment: @Aldiyar How did you make `navigationController` available collection view cell? If not aren't you getting any errors?

Comment: i know its not working ,,. because your cell cant navigate ...

Comment: @Frankenstein No, I didn't make it. No errors, everything is fine, but it just doesnt go to next page. I added push to navigationbar items and it Worked!. But not in cell

Comment: @jawadAli  I didn't understand "use closure or delegate pattern to navigate" Could you please send some links or write more details ) tbh im learning swift only 2nd month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate or closure to do this

```
class ItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   var onTapGesture: (() -> ())?
}
```

Then in your function you do

```
    @objc func labelTapped() {
       
         onTapGesture?()
    }
```

And in your controller

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {
    //...
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = // dequeue cell
        cell.onTapGesture = { [unowned self] in
            let nextVC = NextViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
           
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this same as my answer? You could have added the delegate method instead.

Comment: delegate method is not recommended for just one tap call ... to write protocol and functions ....

Comment: i suggest to use closure .... before your answer ... and write one for him .... i was in between when you post answer ...

Comment: Yeah, I posted the answer first. Thought you weren't planning on posting one.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

what `self` are you referring to ? because you cant make push in child class
you have HomeController i assume its your parent controller .

just try to debug what `self` is this could attempt by debugging or debug by condition

```
print (self)
if (self.isKind(of: YourParentController.self)) {
// make push
}
```

or try to check , see if navigationcontroller somehow has nil value

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it using closures. I've created a `closure` parameter in `UICollectionViewCell` sub-class. When the label gesture target is hit I call the closure which then executed the navigation in `HomeController`.

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {
    //...
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = // dequeue cell
        cell.labelTap = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let nextVC = NextViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
            print("navigated")
        }
        return cell
    }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var labelTap: (() -> Void)?
    @objc func labelTapped() {
        print("labelTapped tapped")
        labelTap?()
    }
}
```